# Vector bundles on $K3$ surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

$\underline {Background}$ : Let $$ be a vector bundle on a $3$ surface  which is globally generated away from a finite set of points. We assume that $^0(^∗)=0$. Then from the exact sequence
$0 \to  \to ^0()\otimes \mathcal O_ \to  \to _→0$
(where $,_$ are respectively kernel and cokernel of the evaluation map) we have another exact sequence
$0 \to ^∗ \to ^0()^∗ \otimes \mathcal O_ \to ^∗ \to \mathcal E ^2(_,\mathcal O_) \to 0$.
Let's denote $_:=\mathcal E^2(_,\mathcal O_)$.
Then we essentially end up having following two S.E.S of vector spaces:

$0 \to (^0())^∗ \to ^0() \to ^1(^∗)\to 0.....(1)$

and
$ 0\to ^0() \to ^0(^∗) \to ^0(_)→0....(2)$
where $=(^0()^* \otimes \mathcal O_)/^∗$.

At this point it's true that " the vector space $=^0()^∗\oplus ^0(_)$ generates $^∗$" using the S.E.S $(1)$ and $(2)$
and the previous discussion.

$\underline {Question(1)}$: Is the following argument for the above fact correct?

$\underline {Attempt}$:  We have  the exact sequence

$0 \to K \to ((H^0(E))^* \oplus H^0(R_E)) \otimes \mathcal O_X \to V^* \to cokerf \to 0$(where $f$ is the the evaluation map at the middle).

If we assume that   $\mathcal Hom(cokerf, \mathcal O_X)$  and $\mathcal Ext^1(cokerf, \mathcal O_X) = 0$(being supported on a finite set(why?)).  Then one can show that $V^{**} \cong \mathcal Hom(Imf , \mathcal O_X)$. From there can one conclude $Imf =V^*$?

$\underline {Question(2)}$: How from  the previous discussion we end up having the exact sequence : $0→^∗→G^∗→^0(_)\otimes \mathcal O_X→_→0$?

(where $G$ is the dual of the kernel of the surjective evaluation map for $V^*$)

$\underline {Attempt}$: We have  the exact sequence

$0 \to K^{'} \to  H^0(R_E)) \otimes \mathcal O_X \to R_E \to cokerg \to 0$(where $g$ is the the evaluation map at the middle).

If we assume that   $\mathcal Hom(cokerg, \mathcal O_X)$  and $\mathcal Ext^1(cokerg, \mathcal O_X) = 0$(being supported on a finite set(why?)).  Then one can show that $R_E^{*} \cong \mathcal Hom(Im(g) , \mathcal O_X)$. From there can one conclude $R_E = Im(g)$?.  If we assume that this gives the surjection of $g$,  then we already have the right end of the desired exact sequence. Also we can give a map $G^* \to H^0(R_E) \otimes \mathcal O_X$. But I don,t see how to show exactness at that point and also how to complete the sequence at the left.

Any help from anyone is welcome.